# How to find all records with empty files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Suppose i have a model with carrierwave file upload.

```
   class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    mount_uploader :file, BookImageUploader

    end
```

If i want to check if a book doesnt have any attached file then i do

```
Book.last.file.file.nil?
```

Now i need to find all records with where clause so that it finds all records that doesnt have attached files.

Something like

```
Book.where(file.file: nil)
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: `Book.where(file: nil)` should be enough. `file.file` is a virtual attribute of Carrerierwave Uploader.

Comment: sorry that doesnt work. file is never nil. file returns uploader object. It is also mentioned in the documentation Note: u.avatar will never return nil, even if there is no photo associated to it. To check if a photo was saved to the model, use u.avatar.file.nil? instead.. Please check https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave under ActiveRecord

Comment: It says `u.avatar` will never return `nil`. But `Book.where(file: nil)` makes the query in database to retrieve things correctly. `Book.where(file:nil).first.file` will not be `nil`, but the query will return all those books for which file doesn't exist

Comment: see https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L139-L198 - it just exposes the methods, making you think that `u.avatar` is not nil. It has nothing to do with what's persisted in database. `Book.where(file:nil).first.read_attribute(:file) == nil`

Comment: I did you consider to query the serialized JSON metadata? Can you please add two examples how carrierwave stores its metadata in the database column - one for a Book with a file and one for a Book without? It's hard to extract the format just from reading carrierwave's source code. What database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the gem adds file column to the table. So this worked for me

```
Book.where("file is null")
```